# how to create a local storage for the saved files using kivy python

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

After deploying it into apk file and testing it. The problem that I encountered was after saving the file name, it crashes and my images don't show up.

I tried using the code from the kivy doc, which is what I'm currently using right now, but I'd like to have my own local storage where the user can save it there and can easily retrieve it.

main.py

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, OptionProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
import shutil
import os
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen


class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class SaveDialog(FloatLayout):
    save = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


class Root(FloatLayout):
    pass


class Cluster(Widget):
    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename[0])) as stream:
            self.text_input.text = stream.read()

        self.dismiss_popup()

    def clustering(self):
        return


class MyFigure(Widget):
    savefile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)
    open('save_file.csv', 'w').write("Shot type,X,Y\n")

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.canvas.add(Color(rgb=(46 / 255.0, 172 / 255.0, 88 / 255.0)))
        d = 10
        self.canvas.add(Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y), size=(d, d)))
        with open('save_file.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
            print("Made," + str(touch.x) + "," + str(touch.y), file=f)

            if touch.is_double_tap:
                self.canvas.add(Color(rgb=(220 / 255.0, 8 / 255.0, 8 / 255.0)))
                d = 10
                self.canvas.add(
                    Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y), size=(d, d)))
                print("Missed," + str(touch.x) + "," + str(touch.y), file=f)

    def clear_screen(self):
        self.canvas.after.clear()

    def save(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(MDApp.get_running_app().user_data_dir, filename), 'w') as stream:
            stream.write(self.text_input.text)

        self.dismiss_popup()


class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    pass


class PlotScreen(MDScreen):
    savefile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_save(self):
        content = SaveDialog(save=self.save, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Save file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(MDApp.get_running_app().user_data_dir, filename[0])) as stream:
            self.text_input.text = stream.read()

        self.dismiss_popup()

    def save(self, path, filename):
        shutil.move("save_file.csv", os.path.join(MDApp.get_running_app().user_data_dir, filename))

        self.dismiss_popup()


class VisualScreen(MDScreen):
    loadfile = ObjectProperty(None)
    text_input = ObjectProperty(None)

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def show_load(self):
        content = LoadDialog(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file", content=content,
                            size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()

    def load(self, path, filename):
        with open(os.path.join(MDApp.get_running_app().user_data_dir, filename[0])) as stream:
            self.text_input.text = stream.read()

        self.dismiss_popup()


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):
    # _user_data_dir = ""
    media = OptionProperty('M', options=('XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'))

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(size=self.update_media)
        Builder.load_file("app.kv")
        return WindowManager()

    def update_media(self, win, size):
        width, height = size
        self.media = (
            'XS' if width < 250 else
            'S' if width < 500 else
            'M' if width < 1000 else
            'L' if width < 1200 else
            'XL'
        )


Factory.register('Root', cls=Root)
Factory.register('LoadDialog', cls=LoadDialog)
Factory.register('SaveDialog', cls=SaveDialog)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

app.kv

```
 <WindowManager>:
    MainScreen:
    PlotScreen:
    VisualScreen:


<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        height: self.minimum_height
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDLabel:
                text: "logo"
                font_size: 20
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6, "center_y": .1}
            Image:
                source: 'images/bball_dude_new.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": .1}
                size_hint: 15, 15

        MDBoxLayout:
            MDCard:
                size_hint: .7, 1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                elevation: 5
                radius: 20
                md_bg_color: 246/255,245/255,241/255

                MDFloatLayout:
                    Widget:
                    Button:
                        background_normal: 'images/dataset.png'
                        background_down: 'images/dataset_clicked.png'
                        size_hint: .15, .35
                        pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': .5}
                        on_release: app.root.current = 'plot'
                    MDLabel:
                        color: 144/255,163/255,167/255
                        text: "Data Gathering"
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 1.02, 'y': .32}
                        font_style: 'Subtitle2'
                    MDLabel:
                        color: 147/255,84/255,48/255
                        text: "Create New Dataset"
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 1.02, 'y': .25}
                        font_style: 'Button'
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "save the data points into \ncsv file and save scatter \nplot output"
                        color: 144/255,163/255,167/255
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 1.02, 'y': .13}
                        font_size: 10
                        font_style: 'Caption'
                    Widget:
                    Button:
                        background_normal: 'images/visualization.png'
                        background_down: 'images/visualization_clicked.png'
                        size_hint: .15, .35
                        pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': .1}
                        on_release: app.root.current = 'visual'
                    MDLabel:
                        color: 144/255,163/255,167/255
                        text: "Visualization"
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 1.02, 'top': .93}
                        font_style: 'Subtitle2'
                        text_size: self.width, None
                    MDLabel:
                        color: 147/255,84/255,48/255
                        text: "Get Data Visualization"
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 1.02, 'top': .85}
                        font_size: 15
                        font_style: 'Button'
                    MDLabel:
                        color: 144/255,163/255,167/255
                        text: "get the data points and start \nclustering to see results \nof a player"
                        font_size: 10
                        font_style: 'Caption'
                        pos_hint: {'center_x': 1.02, 'top': .72}


<PlotScreen>:
    name: 'plot'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        size: 500, 500

        RelativeLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 1
            MDCard:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: "360dp", "350dp"
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
                elevation: 5
                md_bg_color: 246/255,245/255,241/255
            Image:
                source: 'images/half-court.png'

            MyFigure:
                size_hint: .9, .8


        MDBottomNavigation:
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "btnSave"
                text: "Save"
                selected_color_background: 0, 0, 1, .4
                icon: "images/save.png"
                on_tab_release: root.show_save()



            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "btnClear"
                text: "Clear Screen"
                icon: "images/clear.png"
                selected_color_background: 0, 0, 1, .4


            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: "btnBack"
                text: "Home"
                icon: "images/home.png"
                selected_color_background: 0, 0, 1, .4
                on_tab_release: app.root.current = 'main'



<VisualScreen>:
    name: 'visual'
    MDBoxLayout:
        Cluster:

    MDBottomNavigation:
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "btnLoad"
            text: "Get Dataset"
            selected_color_background: 0, 0, 1, .4
            icon: "images/analysis.png"
            on_tab_release: root.show_load()

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "btnSave"
            text: "Save"
            selected_color_background: 0, 0, 1, .4
            icon: "images/save.png"

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "btnBack"
            text: "Home"
            icon: "images/home.png"
            selected_color_background: 0, 0, 1, .4
            on_tab_release: app.root.current = 'main'

<LoadDialog>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)

<SaveDialog>:
    text_input: text_input
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser
            on_selection: text_input.text = self.selection and self.selection[0] or ''

        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            multiline: False

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:
                text: "Save"
                on_release: root.save(filechooser.path, text_input.text)
```

Comment: Use the user data directory. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.user_data_dir).

Comment: @JohnAnderson hi, can you give me an example? I'm quite new to kivy python. Thank you

Comment: In your code where you are using `path` as a path to a folder where you want to save a file, replace `path` with `MDApp.get_running_app().user_data_dir`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson do i replace all the "path"? i keep getting this error too _Logger.exception('unable to access to <%s>' % fn)
 Message: 'unable to access to <C:\\swapfile.sys>'
 Arguments: ()_

Comment: Please include your `app.kv` file in your post.

Comment: @JohnAnderson i included the app.kv, and ive edited the path you were saying, please let me know if that was correct. Thank you

Comment: Having trouble following the logic of your code, but I would suggest adding `path: app.user_data_dir` under `FileChooserListView` in both your load and save dialogs. Then you don't need the changes I suggested earlier. This will consistently direct the user to a folder specific to your app.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Hi, thank you. If this were on an android phone where would the files most likely to be located?

Comment: /data/data/<package_name> It is a folder that is private to the app.

Comment: @JohnAnderson How can you put it to the internal storage?

Comment: That is internal storage.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Sorry, what I meant was the storage where the user can easily find or locate the file